# How can I set some data before executing another code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, async-await, vuejs3

I'm trying to set my geolocation data first before executing another code. Turns out it gives me the initial data if I make it like this. Is there a way to wait for the first code finished to be executed and after the data is available, I can execute the code below the first code?

```
<template>
  <button @click="start">Start</button>
</template>

<script>
  import { ref } from "vue";

  export default {
    data() {
     return {
       latitude: ref(0),
       longitude: ref(0)
     };
    },
    methods: {
      start() {
        this.getLocation(); // execute this first
        console.log(this.latitude, this.longitude); // execute this after the data is updated
    },
    getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPosition);
            } else {
              alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
            }
      },
  showPosition(position) {
     this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
     this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Use promises like **await this.getLocation();**. getLocation function should return new Promise that is resolved when latitude and longitude  are setted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. return a `Promise` from `this.getLocation()`
2. convert `start()` to `async start()` so you can use `await` keyword within the function

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      latitude: ref(0),
      longitude: ref(0),
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async start() {
      const success = await this.getLocation(); // execute this first
      if (success) {
          console.log(this.latitude, this.longitude); // execute this after the data is updated
      } else {
          alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
      }
    },
    getLocation() {
      return Promise((resolve) => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
            this.showPosition(pos);
            resolve(true);
          })
        } else {
          resolve(false)
        }
      });
    },
    showPosition(position) {
      this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It's the same with the way I don't use the promises and async-await. The data is updated when the button is clicked for the second time. The first time doesn't have any effect on changing the data. I wonder why the first click doesn't update the data.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I made mistake. Gimme a sec.

Comment: `if (navigator.geolocation) {` - when false this will result in pending promise

Comment: It works. Thank you. What is the difference between .bind(this) and pos => {
            this.showPosition(pos); resolve()} ?